# Using CUDA Thrust algorithms sequentially on the host

Tags: cuda, thrust

I wish to compare a Thrust algorithm's runtime when executed sequentially on a single CPU core versus a parallel execution on a GPU.

Thrust specifies the [`thrust::seq` execution policy](http://thrust.github.io/doc/group__execution__policies.html#ga88184f5729650369507a73899a1c8d32), but how can I explicity target the host backend system? I wish to avoid executing the algorithm sequentially on the GPU.

Comment: `thrust::host` targets the host backend explicitly. `thrust::seq` always executes sequentially in the calling thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CUDA Thrust is **architecture agnostic**. Accordingly, consider the code I provided as an answer to

[Cumulative summation in CUDA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25251335/cumulative-summation-in-cuda/28657750#28657750)

In that code, `MatingProbability` and `CumulativeProbability` were `thrust::device_vector`s. `thrust::transform` and `thrust::inclusive_scan` were automatically able to recognize that and operate accordingly on the GPU.

Below, I'm providing the same code by changing `thrust::device_vector` to `thrust::host_vector`. Again, `thrust::transform` and `thrust::inclusive_scan` are able to automatically recognize that the vectors to operate on reside on the CPU and to operate accordingly.

```
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/transform.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/counting_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/constant_iterator.h>
#include <cstdio>

template <class T>
struct scaling {
    const T _a;
    scaling(T a) : _a(a) { }
    __host__ __device__ T operator()(const T &x) const { return _a * x; }
};

void main()
{
   const int N = 20;

   double a = -(double)N;
   double b = 0.;

   double Dx = -1./(0.5*N*(N+1));

   thrust::host_vector<double> MatingProbability(N);
   thrust::host_vector<double> CumulativeProbability(N+1, 0.);

   thrust::transform(thrust::make_counting_iterator(a), thrust::make_counting_iterator(b), MatingProbability.begin(), scaling<double>(Dx));

   thrust::inclusive_scan(MatingProbability.begin(), MatingProbability.end(), CumulativeProbability.begin() + 1);

   for(int i=0; i<N+1; i++) 
   {
      double val = CumulativeProbability[i];
      printf("%d %3.15f\n", i, val);
   }

}
```

Comment: Does this mean that Thrust will never transfer data between host and device memory spaces by itself, always operating using processors "closest" to the input data?

Comment: @lodhb Yes, in the code above you will observe no host->device memory transfer. You may wish to analyze it by the NVIDIA Visual Profiler.